Integral limits for $u=y-x$ and $v=y+x$ in $\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}e^{\tfrac{y-x}{y+x}}dydx$
In order to evaluate the following integral, I used the change of variables $u=y-x$ and $v=y+x$.
$$\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}e^{\tfrac{y-x}{y+x}}dydx$$
We have $0\le x\le2$ and $0\le y\le 2-x$. Using $y=\dfrac{v+u}2$ and $x=\dfrac{v-u}{2}$, The limits are
$$0\le x\le 2\quad\Rightarrow\quad0\le v-u\le4$$
$$0 \le y\quad\Rightarrow\quad 0\le v+u$$
$$y\le 2-x\quad\Rightarrow\quad v\le 2$$
From here I'm not sure how to determine the integral limits for $\int\int J\times e^{u/v}dudv$.

Note, that sides of your triangle $x=0, y=0, y=2-x$ gives on $uv$ plane lines $u=v, u=-v, u=2$ respectively. From here more easy will be if you take $u$ as independent variable (this gives one integral).

@zkutch Thanks, I could proceed with your help.

In polar coordinates it becomes
$$
\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}e^{\tfrac{y-x}{y+x}}dydx
{
=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^\frac{2}{\sin\phi+\cos\phi}e^{\tfrac{\sin\phi-\cos\phi}{\sin\phi+\cos\phi}}rdrd\phi
\\=
\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{\tfrac{\sin\phi-\cos\phi}{\sin\phi+\cos\phi}}\frac{2}{(\sin\phi+\cos\phi)^2}d\phi
\\=
\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{\tan(\phi-\pi/4)}\frac{1}{\cos^2(\phi-\pi/4)}d\phi
\\=
2\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{\tan\phi}\frac{1}{\cos^2\phi}d\phi
\\=
2e^{\tan\phi}|_0^{\pi/4}=2e-2.
}
$$
